# Razor shows syntax error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, razor

I am not able to understand why the following code is marked as "syntax error" in Visual Studio (however, it compiles and runs ok):

```
<script>
    var clientTypeEnum = @EnumExtension.ConvertToJson(typeof(ClientTypeEnum)) ; 
</script>
```

Comment: which error does it show ?

Comment: the implicit state-switching Razor does is somewhat complex; there are times when the IDE gets things wrong (usually sacrificing correctness for speed), especially when you mix javascript + Razor.